# space after the forum word in vBulletin

Tags: vbulletin

Actually i had a problem while making my style i finished it all but i faced a problem ,,
[THIS PIC](http://im37.gulfup.com/kSnto.png) shows the problem.
How can i remove this huge space after the forum word at the beginning of the categories?
is it related too the certain tag ?? or this is a mistake that i changed or added a value for the wrong class ??
There is a floatcontainer tag i think this is the tag that has the error.
the code of this part is :

```
    <div id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
<ul class="floatcontainer">
<li class="navbithome">
<li class="navbit lastnavbit">
<span>forum</span>
</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Give us the CSS as well.

Comment: Provide me with your CSS and I will help you.